# Find $y,z \in [a, b]$ such that $h(y) = h(z)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a < b$ be two real numbers, and let $f : [a, b] \to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $f(a) = f(b)$ and $f'(a) = 0$. Let $h(x) = e^{−x}\bigl(f(x) + f'(x)\bigr)$. Find $y,z \in [a, b]$ such that $h(y) = h(z)$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this question is well posed, aside from the fact that, as currently stated, differentiability at the endpoints is not well defined.

Assuming the necessary adjustments I still don't think the problem can be solved. To see this consider the constant function $$f(x) = c$$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Clearly this satisfies the (modified) requirements. However, if there exist $y,z \in (a,b)$ for which the desired equality holds, then we would have $$e^{-y}(f(y)+f^\prime(y)) = e^{-z}(f(z)+f^\prime(z)) \Rightarrow e^{-y} = e^{-z} \Rightarrow y = z,$$which is the trivial solution (and hence a contradiction, assuming you want a non-trivial solution).

Comment: Thanks for the input although I think it could be solved. If f'(y)=-f(y) and f'(x)=-f(x) then y need not be equal to z to satisfy h(y)=h(z)=0.